# algortimo para ler idade anos, meses, e anos e converter o valor para a idade apenas em dias

Tags: c, c++, algoritmo

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main() {
 int idade;
 int anos;
 int meses;
 int dias;
  
cin >> anos >> meses >> dias;

 meses= anos*12;



 dias= meses*30;

 cout << ("sua idade em dias:");

 




 
 





                       
 
}
```

No caso ele ta aparecendo pra eu digitar o valor em dias, mas ele que deveria responder e nao eu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que acumular e ao final imprimir a quantidade de dias.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
int main() {
    int anos, meses, dias;
    cin >> anos >> meses >> dias;
    cout << "Anos: " << anos << endl;
    cout << "Meses: " << meses << endl;
    cout << "Dias: " << dias << endl;
    meses += anos*12;
    dias += meses*30;
    cout << "Sua idade em dias: " << dias << endl;;
    return 0;
}
```